# Number of observations by two variables in R

Tags: r

How do I find number of observation meeting both criteria BF between 10-15 and p between 20-24?

```
BF = rnorm(50,10,2)
p = rnorm(50,20,4)
es = rnorm(50,40,8)
evidence = data.frame(BF,p,es)
```

Comment: Please consult http://www.sscce.org for how to construct a question solidly.

Comment: `dim(with(evidence, evidence[BF > 10 & BF < 15 & p > 20 & p < 24, ]))[1]`

Answer (score 1):

```
nrow(evidence[with(evidence,BF > 10 & BF < 15 & p > 20 & p < 24),])
```

Comment: You need to specify a column or else you're taking the length of a list: `length(evidence[with(evidence,BF > 10 & BF < 15 & p > 20 & p < 24), 1])`.  Otherwise you could use `nrow`:  `nrow(evidence[with(evidence,BF > 10 & BF < 15 & p > 20 & p < 24),])`